# Set theory, ordinals

Tags: set-theory

Let $\varphi(x)$ be a set theoretical property. We say that $\varphi$ is transitive on the ordinals if:

$$(\forall \alpha)(\forall \beta)[(\alpha \in \beta\ \wedge \varphi(\beta)) \Rightarrow \varphi(\alpha)].$$

Prove that, if $\varphi$ is transitive on the ordinals, then: 
If it doesn't exist set $A$, such that $(\forall \alpha)[\alpha \in A \Longleftrightarrow \varphi(\alpha)]$, then $\forall \alpha (\varphi(\alpha)).$

I suppose that somehow I have to use the transfinite induction principle. But what stops me is that I have no idea what is $\varphi$, I only know it's transitive. So how to prove the base case of the empty set? So I met difficulties with this approach, probably, it's not correct. 

Any help would be sincerely appreciated!

Comment: Suppose for contradiction that it is not the case that $\forall\alpha(\varphi(\alpha))$. Then there is some $\alpha$ for which $\neg\varphi(\alpha)$. In that case, what can you say about $\varphi(\beta)$ for other ordinals $\beta$? For example, does $\varphi(\alpha + 1)$ hold?

Comment: @ReeseJohnston Because of the transitivity of $\varphi$, it would be $\neg \varphi(\beta)$ for all ordinals greater than $\alpha$. But I still doesn't see the contradiction. Could you give me a little more details?

Comment: @ReeseJohnston I probably have to show that it DOESN'T exists set $A$, because in this case the whole implication would be false. Am I right, or?

Comment: @Paul You’re trying to prove the contrapositive, so you want to show there *is* such a set. If you let $\alpha$ be the least ordinal such that $\lnot\varphi(\alpha)$, then $\alpha$ is that set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"There doesn't exist a set of all ordinals $\alpha$ such that $\varphi(\alpha)$" means that the class $C$ of all such ordinals is unbounded: for every $\alpha$, there is $\beta > \alpha$ with $\varphi(\beta)$.

Given $\alpha$, let $\beta > \alpha$ be such that $\varphi(\beta)$. Because $C$ is transitive, it contains $\alpha$ — that is, $\varphi(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose not, that is, $\exists\gamma(\neg\phi(\gamma))$. Let $\gamma$ be the least-such ordinal. We claim $A=\gamma$ is a set where $\forall\alpha[\alpha\in A\Leftrightarrow \phi(\alpha)]$.

If $\alpha\in A$, then $\alpha<\gamma$, and therefore $\phi(\alpha)$.

If $\phi(\alpha)$, suppose $\gamma\leq\alpha$. By transitivity, $\phi(\gamma)$, a contradiction. Thus $\alpha<\gamma$ and therefore $\alpha\in A$.